# How can I write this in better way in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I am trying to write a function where I have a data LP and based on the value of the LP, there will be some output.

```
def data(lp,matrix):
    if (lp<20):
        T52 = lp*matrix.t1[0] + matrix.t2[0]            
        return T52

    elif (lp>=20) and (lp<30):
        T52 = lp*matrix.t1[1] + matrix.t2[2]
        return T52

    elif (lp>=30) and (lp<50):
        T52 = lp*matrix.t1[3] + matrix.t2[3]
        return T52

    elif (lp>=50) and (lp<65):
        T52 = lp*matrix.t1[4] + matrix.t2[4]
        return T52

    elif (lp>=65) and (lp<80):
        T52 = lp*matrix.t1[5] + matrix.t2[5]
        return T52

    elif (lp>=80):
        T52 = lp*matrix.t1[6] + matrix.t2[6]
        return T52
```

Comment: I think you mean `and`, not `&`. Also you don't need to recheck all the excluded conditions in `elif`s.

Comment: You don't need the `>=` check. If it goes into the `elif`, it means the value *is* `>=` than the last `<` check.

Comment: Is it on purpose that t1 and t2 always have the same indices, except for `lp>=20 and lp<30`?

Comment: @khelwood Yes you are right, thats "and" not "&" there. My mistake.

Comment: Consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also consider marking an answer as correct if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a looped version of it, it requires some finesse, due to the inconsistent indices:

```
def data(lp,matrix):
    splits = [20, 30, 40, 65, 80]
    indices = [(0,0), (1,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6)]
    for split, (id1, id2) in zip(splits, indices):
        if lp < split:
            return lp*matrix.t1[id1] + matrix.t2[id2]
    return lp*matrix.t1[indices[-1][0]] + matrix.t2[indices[-1][1]]
```

But to be honest, I would just leave it unrolled, I think it is easier to read.

```
def data(lp,matrix):
    if lp<20:
        return lp*matrix.t1[0] + matrix.t2[0]

    elif lp<30:
        return lp*matrix.t1[1] + matrix.t2[2]

    elif lp<50:
        return lp*matrix.t1[3] + matrix.t2[3]

    elif lp<65:
        return lp*matrix.t1[4] + matrix.t2[4]

    elif lp<80:
        return lp*matrix.t1[5] + matrix.t2[5]

    else:
        return lp*matrix.t1[6] + matrix.t2[6]
```

Comment: Its a similar approach to what I have already written. What I am looking for to not have if else. Maybe can be done with for loops?

Comment: @TanayRastogi if you would answer if the inconsistend indices of lp<30 are on purpose, I could give you an answer to that

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put everything in a loop? seems much cleaner to me.

```
bounds = [20,30,50,65,80]
n = len(bounds)
for i, bound in enumerate(bounds):
    if lp < bound:
        return lp*matrix.t1[i] + matrix.t2[i]
return lp * matrix.t1[n] + matrix.t2[n]
```

Edit: 
So I was being a little blind, not seeing the indices werent consisting with a loop. You could still opt for such a solution, simply keeping a list of indices

```
bounds = [20,30,50,65,80]
idxs = [(0,0), (1,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6)]
for i,bound in enumerate(bounds):
    if lp<bound:
        return lp*matrix.t1[idxs[i][0]] + matrix.t2[idxs[i][1]]
return lp*matrix.t1[idxs[-1][0]] + matrix.t2[idxs[-1][1]]
```

Which might be useful if you have more cases.. Otherwise I would probably just go with the other answer for simplicity reasons.

Comment: Not the same result…

Comment: Guess Im confused.. how so?

Comment: This could be improved by replacing `for i in range(n):` with `for i, bound in enumerate(bounds):`, removing the need for `n`, and avoiding indexing `bounds` each loop, replacing the `if` with `if lp < bound:`. Otherwise, this is exactly the way to go.

Comment: @Banana in his code, the indices of t1 and t2 are not always the same, neither do they go up by one very time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger good point. Ill edit that in.

Im guessing the "wrong result" is because one of the cases has a non-consistent index that I just saw.. well, if thats not a mistake, then this actually doesnt work.

Comment: I will also want to have a fool loop, but as @deceze said, not the same result. I have different matrix index for bound lp<30

Comment: @Banana: It can be made to work by adding a `tuple` of indices to iterate over in parallel with the bounds to check.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Actually just what I figured out a second ago and edited in as well. Just thinking that its not as clean anymore, maybe.

Comment: `n=len(bounds)` is unnecessary, just replace `idxs[n,0]` with `idxs[-1,0]`

Comment: @Finomnis True. Thanks

Comment: @Banana if you now zip() ids and bounds to get rid of the unnecessary indexing, we have the same answer ;)

Comment: @Finomnis haha true. Didnt want to do that because of the different lengths of bounds and idxs, makes it a little weird :) (I know its correct, just speaking in terms of readability to me)

Comment: @Banana nah it's fine, zip only iterates until the shortest iterator is finished, which is exactly what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bisect, with the added benefit of more efficient comparison logic:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def data(lp,matrix):
    control = [     20,    30,    50,    65,    80     ]
    indexes = [(0,0), (1,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6)]
    c       = bisect_left(lp,control)
    i,j     = indexes[c]
    return lp*matrix.t1[i] + matrix.t2[j]
```